ORA-00905: missing keyword (Oracle SQL Live)
This is my Oracle SQL query:
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SAL IS NOT NULL THEN 1) AS SALARIED_DEPT30,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COMM IS NOT NULL THEN 1) AS COMM_DEPT30
FROM
    EMP
WHERE 
    DEPTNO = 30;

I get this message:

ORA-00905: missing keyword

What am I missing?
My aim is to query the column DEPTNO selecting for 30 and counting how many employees have a salary and also querying how many receive commission. I am trying to get the two separate counts (independent of each other) in one query.
What I am trying to avoid is something such as:
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM EMP
WHERE DEPTNO = 30 
  AND SAL IS NOT NULL 
  AND COMM IS NOT NULL;

While it runs, I do not want to receive a table of only employees where SAL and COMM are both NOT NULL.

See the docs on how a CASE ... END expession has to look like  (hint: I don't see a END in your query).

I think you don't need CASE here, but simply write COUNT(SAL) and COUNT(COMM). NULL will be ignored by COUNT.

A CASE expression is terminated by END.
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN SAL IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS SALARIED_DEPT30,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN COMM IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS COMM_DEPT30
FROM   EMP
WHERE  DEPTNO = 30;

However, aggregation functions typically ignore NULL values so you can simplify it to:
SELECT COUNT(SAL) AS SALARIED_DEPT30,
       COUNT(COMM) AS COMM_DEPT30
FROM   EMP
WHERE  DEPTNO = 30;

